# split a String with a separator in trailing position in Scala

Tags: scala

The method `split` do NOT deal with the separator in trailing position.

```
@ "a-b-".split("-")
res9: Array[String] = Array("a", "b")
```

However, I would expect `Array("a", "b", "")`

Any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may pass additional parameter `limit` to the function (which is zero by default):

```
scala> "a-b-".split("-", -1)
res3: Array[String] = Array(a, b, "")

scala> "-----".split("-", -1)
res4: Array[String] = Array("", "", "", "", "", "")
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length.** If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Comment: I can't find a split with a second argument in Scala 2.12. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not a scala method. See the link in the post, this is a java method.